# How to initialize complicated array JS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

I use TypeScript for create array:

```
private menuItems: Menu[][];
```

After in loop I try to fill this like:

```
this.menuItems[role].push(this.menu[i]);
```

In result I want to get the following:

```
[1 : [{obj}, {obj}], 2: [{obj}, {obj}], 3: [{obj}, {obj}]]
```

What I do wrong?

Full code is:

```
public getMenuByRole(role: number): Menu[][] {
    for ( let i = 0; i < this.menu.length; i++ ) {
      if (this.menu[i].role === role && this.menu[i].avaliable) {
          this.getTranslateMenuItem(this.menu[i].title).subscribe((translation: string) => {
            this.menu[i].title = translation;
            this.menuItems[role].push(this.menu[i]);
          });
      }
    }
    return this.menuItems;
  }
```

**Problem is that I try to add new objecti in array by custom key array, that is not exist**

I tried also this:

```
const obj = {};
const arr = Array();
```

The in loop:

```
arr.push(this.menu[i]);
obj[role].push(arr);
```

Comment: please, show some relative code you have written for it and also error, if you are getting one.

Comment: This is full code. I initialize array [][], and tried to fill it

Comment: what does `this.menu` contains? Maybe you can show some sample data.

Comment: I guess, that it should be object of array like as: `{1 : [{}. {}], 2: [{}, {}] }`

Comment: Okay, see updating

Comment: Aside:  I might invert your logic such that the menu item knows what roles it can be shown to.  Each menu item could have `children: menuItem[]`. This way you can build your menu graph without a complex array.

Comment: I need something like: `[1 : [{obj}, {obj}], 2: [{obj}, {obj}], 3: [{obj}, {obj}]]` ,then to get array of links by key from array:  `1 => [{link}, {link}]`

Comment: Problem is that I try to add new objecti in array by custom key array, that is not exist

Comment: Since you have `this.menu = {1 : [{}, {}], 2: [{}, {}] }` and you want to access like `var[1], var[2]`. You can do that with object also. Please just try returning `this.menu` from the above function.

Comment: I dont understand what do you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create an array inside an array to get a two dimensional array.
I would use an object though. Hope this is what you are looking for

```
class A {
 private menu: [];

 constructor(){

 this.menu = new Array();
 for(let i = 0; i< 10; i++){
    let menuItem = new Array();
    menuItem.push(new B(i));
    menuItem.push(new B(i+1));
    this.menu.push(menuItem);
  }
  console.log(this.menu);
 }
}

class B {

 constructor(public x: int){
 }
}

new A();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/64r04pp2/